# How to use Maven with HTTPS repos via proxy?

Tags: maven

How do I configure Maven to use a proxy with HTTPS resources? It seems not to work with the settings in `xxx\.m2\settings.xml`? (HTTP yes, but not HTTPS)

I am behind my company's squid proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took way too long to figure out, but the solution proposed [here (german)](http://entwickler-forum.de/showthread.php/63695-Snippet-Maven2-gleichzeitig-mit-http-und-https-Proxy-mit-Eintr%C3%A4gen-in-Datei-m2-conf) works:

In your Maven installation directory, under the `bin` subfolder, there is an `m2.conf` file. Adding your proxy settings as follows works:

```
set https.proxyHost default myHost
set https.proxyPort default myPort
```

Omit the mentioned `xxx\.m2\settings.xml` file. 
It is implied that you would also need to add your HTTP Proxy to these settings:

```
set http.proxyHost default myHost
set http.proxyPort default myPort
```